# android logcat spams error messages

Tags: android, logging, usb, logcat, spam

when I connect my android device, logcat shows a lot of error messages and do not stop spaming it. is this normal? anyone know what I can do against it?

log screenshots:

[image: Logcat sample #1]

[image: Logcat sample #2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images you've posted show error messages that are completely unrelated to your app, unless you're working with the BOOT_COMPLETE broadcast and Alarms.

You can simple filter out messages that aren't from your application using a tag in your messages or by filtering with the process ID.

Comment: Thank you! Until now I never used a filter and I could easy read my log messages. But suddenly logcat logs nearly every second error messages. Any idea why?

Comment: @mp5 Usually eclipse almost always creates a filter for your app when you launch it through the run or debug menus. Sometimes this fails for a reason I never figured out, and you see the entire log